# how do we ignore standard library headers and thirdparty libraries from being processed by flexelint

Tags: static-analysis, lint

We are using flexelint for statical analysis on our code base. When running flexelint, we are  seeing  lots of errors in standard C/C++ headers, our standard headers are in a non-standard location. We would like  to skip standard headers being  processed by flexelint. Also we would like to skip other headers coming  from a  thirdparty directory.

Comment: You should post the actual errors you get, your lint configuration file and the output, when you call lint with the -vf function. The -vf option should make lint print out which header files it found and whether it treated it as library header file or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you lint a single file or only a part of your project, you should use the `-u` option. This suppresses warnings in header files that are related to inter-project problems.